# How to make a VB.NET DLL callable in VB6?

Tags: vb.net, dll, com, vb6, interop

I have made a DLL in VS2017 using VB.NET:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<ComClass(ComClass1.ClassId, ComClass1.InterfaceId, ComClass1.EventsId)>
Public Class ComClass1

#Region "COM GUIDs"
    ' These  GUIDs provide the COM identity for this class 
    ' and its COM interfaces. If you change them, existing 
    ' clients will no longer be able to access the class.
    Public Const ClassId As String = "c67bcd70-54d0-4498-97be-a5f954790dec"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "7ef1a8ce-bcc1-464e-8dc3-fc164bdb7ea3"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "9939eabd-1102-4e34-9735-54664e3536bd"
#End Region

    ' A creatable COM class must have a Public Sub New() 
    ' with no parameters, otherwise, the class will not be 
    ' registered in the COM registry and cannot be created 
    ' via CreateObject.
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Xposition As Int32

    Public GoX As Int32

    Public Function MoveX() As Int32
        Dim target As Int32
        target = Convert.ToInt32(Rnd() * 1000)
        Xposition = target
        Return Xposition
    End Function

    Public Function ReadX() As Int32
        Dim target As Int32
        target = Convert.ToInt32(Rnd() * 1000 - GoX)
        Xposition = target
        Return Xposition
    End Function

End Class
```

I compiled the DLL as Administrator on the development Widows 10 PC.
I copied the DLL file to the Windows XP target machine running VB6 and get Run-time error 453. [image]

The VB6 code:

```
Private Declare Function GSCloseServer Lib "GSWDLL32.DLL" () As Long

Private Declare Function MoveX Lib "C:\Temp\VB_Applications\My_DLL_Test\MyNewDLL.dll" () As Integer


Private Sub btnMove_Click()

Call test

End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click()

   Dim Running As Integer

  ' Unload MyGraph
   Set Form1 = Nothing
   Running = GSCloseServer()
   
   If Running = 0 Then
     MsgBox "Close Server OK: " & Running, vbOKOnly
   Else
     MsgBox "Close Server Error " & Running, vbOKOnly
   End If

   Unload Me
   
End Sub

Private Sub test()

'txtbxReadBack.Text = ComClass1.Xposition

txtbxReadBack.Text = MoveX

End Sub
```

I am running VS2017 as administrator, so the DLL appears to be registered properly on the development PC.

Comment: You don't need that constructor. I know the docs say it's required, but in .Net if you don't declare any constructors for a type it will generate the parameterless constructor for you.

Comment: You're building a COM object in VB.NET, so you must call it like a COM object in VB6, not like a standard dll with exports.

Comment: How do I call it as a com object in VB6? I also put the .tlb file in the path of the dll. In the project references, I can select the MyNewDLL.tlb file but not the dll file.

Comment: _How do I call it as a com object in VB6?_ In the vb6 project, select the MyNewDLL interface from Project-References. Then you can define and instantiate the COM objects, eg `Dim oMyDLL = New namespace.ComClass1` and `txtbxReadBack.Text = oMyDLL.MoveX`, remove the function declaration. On test machine, your assembly needs to be registered (regasm.exe). It is probably that the compile of the assembly on the dev machine performed the registering of the assembly.

Comment: To expand on what @SimonMourier said: The line `Private Declare Function MoveX Lib "C:\Temp\VB_Applications\My_DLL_Test\MyNewDLL.dll" () As Integer` is how in VB6 you define the prototype for a standard Win32 DLL. Side note: the declaration would be wrong, as your method returns `Int32`, which is `Long` in VB6/VBA. COM DLLs OTOH are added thru the already mention Project->References menu option - similar to how you add an assembly  in VB.NET. But for your COM DLL to appear as a selection in "References", you need to register it _(also already mentioned)_.

Comment: Quick note (not related to your problem right now), you've declared MoveX as an Int32 in the .Net side, and as an Integer in the VB6 side. A VB6 Integer is 2 bytes, but a .Net Int32 is 4 bytes. You should use a VB6 Long instead which is also 4 bytes.

Comment: The only item that shows up in the VB6 IDE on XP references is MyNewDLL.tlb. The MyNewDLL.dll does not appear, so I can't select it? How do I verify it is a successfully wrapped COM object? I ran regasm.exe, and it appeared successful. On the Win10 development PC running VS2-017 as Administrator, the dll was registered somewhere. I assume that it was on the Win10 PC, but is that encoded in the tlb file or somewhere?

Comment: As mentioned by MarkL, you will select the tlb file in Project References.  Once you set the reference you will be able to New up an instance of the class.  You will know you were successful if you can do this and see the methods in IntelliSense and you are able to call those methods.  Compiling the dll will register it which also allows the system to track down the dll.  If you have trouble, make sure the dll has these 2 settings checked:  "Register for COM interop" and "Make assembly COM-visible".

Comment: The tlb is created by registering the dll and contains the COM interface definitions. Reference the tlb in vb6 Project-References. The registering of the dll also adds registry entries pointing at the tlb and the dll (and the paths for them); don't move the dll without re-registering it. When building the dll, there's a "Register for COM interop" checkbox under (in VS2019) My Project-Compile; when that is checked on, then the dll will be registered by VS during the build. But if you're not referencing the dll on that pc (from vb6, for example), you actually don't need to register it there.

Comment: Continuing the saga, I tried running regsvr32 on the XP target machine to register the dll, and the error "MyNewDLL.dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found. The file cannot be registered."  What might this mean?

Comment: regsvr32.exe is used to register a 'true' COM interface (dll, exe, ocx created by, for instance, vb6). Use regasm.exe to register a .net COM Interop assembly.

Comment: I have referenced the tlb file and when I type New in the IDE, the class ComClass1 is available.   I added the "new": 
Private Sub btnMove_Click()
Call test
End Sub

Private Sub test()
Dim junk As Integer
junk = New ComClass1.MoveX
txtbxReadBack.Text = junk
End Sub

Comment: Now the error is a type mismatch between Junk and the textbox.

Comment: Dim junk as long and assign junk = New ComClass1.MoveX  and I have a type mismatch. MoveX is an Int32?

Comment: `junk = New ComClass1.MoveX` is incorrect.  You will New the class on a separate line of code and then use the MoveX method of the class to assign the value.

Comment: Sorry this is so confusing to me. However: Dim junk as New ComClass1   Dim test as long      test = junk.MoveX, where the autocomplete recognizes MoveX and ReadX exist. The error is now run-time error 429, ActiveX component can't create object.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps. I'll create a very simple "COMVisibleHelloWorld" class library with one class

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

'Create a manual interface so we can use a fixed and known guid for the COM interface.
<Guid("3BBA8F8E-6B35-48E0-91D4-124DC6FCE7B9"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)>
Public Interface IHelloWorld
    <DispId(1)> Function SayHello() As String

End Interface

<Guid("BCDCDA5C-DCAF-4C6C-86BA-03908DBEFF4B"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)>
Public Class HelloWorld
    Implements IHelloWorld

    Public Function SayHello() As String Implements IHelloWorld.SayHello
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function

End Class
```

In Visual Studio select "Make Assembly COM-Visible"

[image]

In Visual Studio create a strong key

[image]

Build the project. This will then create a tlb file.

[image]

You can now reference this is VB6

[image]

To use in VB6 just create an instance, and call the methods that have a COM interface

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim hello As New COMVisibleHelloWorld.HelloWorld
    MsgBox (hello.SayHello)

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I followed the instructions for COMVisibleHelloWorld, but upon compiling no tlb file was created: just the .dll, .pdb. amd .xml.

Comment: OK, I found the "Register for COM interop" checkbox on the compile options menu and selected it. Now I have the tlb file!

Comment: The 32 bit XP, VB6 target machine generates Run-time Error 429, ActiveX component can't create object. I referenced the tlb file.  The public function "SayHello" appears in the autocomplete. I built the dll in both 64 bit and x86 bit configurations. Neither worked. The dll is in the source code directory. I also tried it in System32.  Private Declare Function SayHello Lib "C:\Temp\VB_Applications\My_DLL_Test\COMVisibleHelloWorld.tlb" () As String
Private Sub btnMove_Click()
  Dim hello As New COMVisibleHelloWorld.HelloWorld
  Dim test As String
  MsgBox (hello.SayHello)
End Sub

Comment: I tried to register the dll,, and it says the file can not be registered. I guess this is OK?

Comment: To check if the dll is registered, open command prompt and run: 

"reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes /s /f COMVisibleHelloWorld.dll"

This will search the registry and try to find the dll

Comment: I found the GUID for the public class and for the interface. I did not find the dll in HKLM\software\classes. Maybe that explains the new error, Automation error: the system can't find the file specified, Error 2147024894. This began when I recompiled the dll for the .NET Framework 4 client profile on the XP machine. The autocomplete still finds the HelloWorld.SayHello.

Comment: I ran regasm with the dll path, and XP reported "Types registered successfully." However, still have the error.

Comment: Made a new tlb file with regasm, removed the reference, exited VB6, restarted VB6, added the reference to the new tlb file. Same error.